# Change CSS class based on bound value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an item template in a grid view:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="GroupDescription">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" CssClass="edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GroupDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="lblHidden" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

The CssClass is 'edit'. If the GroupDescription is default then there should be no css class. Is there some way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the class within the ItemDataBound event of the repeater:

```
protected void YourRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (ListItemType.Item == e.Item.ItemType || ListItemType.AlternatingItem == e.Item.ItemType)
        {
          var lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName");
          if(lbl.Text == "something")
            lbl.CssClass = "someCssClass";
        }
}
```